# iPad automatically adding apps

Tags: ios, ipad

I took a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gGp1bb_FnI) of what's happening.

It started when I got a new iPad Air and restored my backup...   in addition to  all of the apps and folders that I had expected to see from my back up, there was also a whole bunch of other apps that my iPad had inserted so that all of my screens are now full. ..when I move or delete apps from any screen, it just shoves apps into any empty space so that all slots on every screen have an app or a folder occupying them and I cannot stop that. The apps it is shoving in there are apps that I have not personally added to the iPad In years!

I have tons of apps attached to my account, Literally thousands because I went crazy trying free apps for many years.  Obviously I don't use them all. But iPad has them available in my appstore account to choose from and it DOES.

Apple support tried, but they were completely unable to figure out what the hell was going on or how to fix it and they landed at: start over from scratch.  Umm... really? Can you begin to imagine the time it took to arrange those screens? (I have *lots* of folders) I believe I would rather go shoot someone.

Obviously I may have to do that if I never find an answer. I am hoping that 15 might fix it, or someone here might have a brilliant solution. Never hurts to ask. (Yes,  this incredibly bizarre issue has  persisted through all updates for almost a year)

To put it simply: can anybody figure out how I might be able to delete and/or move the apps the iPad is adding and have it stop adding more?

All ideas (that preserve the fundamental structure I built originally) are welcome!

Comment: What exactly is th question here? Pleae have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for things we look for in questions.

Comment: I want it to stop doing that! I guess I was relying on the comment I made on the video and I should’ve been more explicit here… But in the video I posted you can see that I move apps to a folder and the spots where I’ve taken the app from immediately filled with another app… And I did not do that! iPad is doing it automatically and I can’t stop it and I have no control over it and it’s making me very unhappy!

Comment: Has this ever worked differently for you? iOS always rearranges App icons automatically, you can‘t have gaps.

Comment: Of course you can... not between icons, but you can have a screen with just a single icon/app.

Comment: Has it something to do with you downloading from iCloud backup? I know you can offload apps that you aren't using when your storage is limited, so I wonder if your iPad has had freed up storage thus allowing iCloud to reinstall them? Additionally, apps you no longer use can be removed from your App store purchase history, which may also help you!